# How to append two results from an i query in Python using bs4?

Tags: python, append

I'm pulling 2 result 1 is the item name and second is the price of each item,

I wanted to see only the text for both the name and the price, but now that I can see it how do I append both to a list?

```
    T_results=soup.findAll('h3',attrs={'class':'s-item__title'})
    Pr_results=soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class':'s-item__price'})

    for i_name in (T_results):
    for i_price in (Pr_results):
```

I need to append the 2 results from each of the **i** results.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to use `i` to mean two different things, which looks inviting trouble.

Comment: @greyberd Thanks! I have added an identifier to each of the i..

Comment: @M.Contreras I'm going to take a guess that you want: `name_prices = list(zip(T_results, Pr_results))`... so that you line up the results

Comment: @jon Clements Thanks Jon... your script worked but without the i_name ot the i_price the list  shows some of the HTLM tags in it. that wa the reason for me to try and use the  i_XXX.

Comment: Then you need to access the `.string` element of what you're after - otherwise, you'll get soup objects which represent themselves as html...

Comment: this what I tried..

Comment: his what I tried..   # Working commands
        T_results=soup.findAll('h3',attrs={'class':'s-item__title'})
        Pr_results=soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class':'s-item__price'})
    

# working missing the T_results this only parses the price correctly 
#the name does only parses the first line and repeats it self on every record. 
       records=[]
       for i_name in T_results:
            name=i_name.text
       for i_price in Pr_results:   
            price=i_price.text
       records.append((price,name))
  

        len (records)

        records[0:4]